# Qtip with fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, qtip

I'm trying to learn qtip for fullcalendar but it doesnt seems to work. I´ve tried all tutorials/examples but nothing works as they say. I'm using the following code but I´ve tried many other alternatives. Am I doing any obvious fault?

```
dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) { 
    $(this).qtip({ 

        content:"",
        overwrite: false,
        position: { corner: { target: 'topMiddle', tooltip: 'bottomMiddle' },
        viewport: $(window), // Keep it on-screen at all times if possible
        adjust: { x: 10, y: 10 } },
        show: { when: 'click', // Don't specify a show event
        ready: true // Show the tooltip when ready },
        hide: { when: 'click' },
        style: { 
        border: {  width: 5, radius: 10 }, 
        padding: 10, 
        textAlign: 'center', //tip: true, 
        // Give it a speech  bubble tip with automatic corner detection name: 'cream' 
        // Style it according to the preset  'cream' style } }); }
```

Answer (score 2):

I used qTip in my fullCalendar app like this:

In eventRender:

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
    element.qtip({
                    content : [HTML SHOWING CONTENT],
                    position: {[position info]}
                    ... rest of settings...
                 });
    },
```

Then when i want the qTip to show (for me in eventMouseover)

```
eventMouseover: function(event) {
        jQuery(this).qtip();
    },
eventMouseout: function(event) {
        jQuery(this).qtip().hide();
    },
```

That is.. In eventRender, setup your qtip using element.qtip and in dayClick just call the $(this).qtip() function.
Not sure why I did it this way, but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the correct CSS and JS file linked in your document head.

```
  <head>
    <!-- STYLESHEETS //-->
      <link type="text/css" rel='stylesheet' href="style/jquery.qtip.min.css">

    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS //-->
      <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
  </head>
```

Once you have those, if you add the following line into the top of eventRender function

```
//Add the qtip to the eventRender function:
    element.qtip({ style: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-jtools', content: event.description});
```

Like this.

```
eventRender: function(event, element) {
//Add the qtip to the event when renered
element.qtip({ style: 'ui-tooltip-shadow ui-tooltip-jtools', content: event.description});
```